# asp.net mvc setting session values with thread safety

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session, thread-safety

In my asp.net MVC project, I have a session helper class that I use to set and retrieve session values. This is the class:

```
public class SessionManager
{
     public static string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session[SessConstants.UName] ;
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[SessConstants.UName] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the properties are static. I use this in my code as below:

```
//For setting values    
SessionManager.UserName = "";

//For retrieving values
strLoggedinUser = SessionManager.UserName;
```

Questions:

1. Are static properties like these thread safe for setting to HttpContext.Current.Session['someVar'] ?
2. Should I create a instance property instead and instantiate the SessionManager in a base controller which I inherit from the MVC controller class. I can then have all my controllers inherit my custom controller instead of the MVC one

Thoughts?

Thanks for your time...

Comment: If you are using SessionManager from withing a controller base or from specific controller instances, then thread safety is not an issue, as a new instance of the controller is created for each request and the session is specific to the session.  However, depending on the load balancing scheme you are using in your environment, the use of session at all may not be advisable.

Comment: Currently SessionManager is in a helper project. The move to enable thread safety was to 1.) make it an instance class with instance properties and 2.) make this class available in a custom base controller class which inherits from the MVC controller class.

Comment: So you're saying that if I just move it as it is now to the custom controller class it will be thread safe? even though the properties are static?

Comment: Yes, because each controller instance is destroyed and created individually, and local to the current thread.  The base class is just a base it's not executing in a seperate context from the controller that implements it. See :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269743/c-sharp-thread-safety-when-referencing-static-properties-on-other-classes

Comment: Great, so what I gather is that moving the SessionManager to a controller as is will also guarantee thread safety, but the current way it is handled, with keeping it in a helper project will not..correct?

Comment: It would be thread safe in it's own project as well, since you would still be executing the objects from that project in the context of a single controller.  I'm not sure what type of authentication scheme you are implementing, but if you are going with claims, I might make the user name part of the claims object and encrypt it to the cookie with the other claims, rather than stashing it in the session, just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a thought. (May not entirely be an answer to your question, but I think Maess handled that in comments.)

Instead of having a separate `SessionManager` class to encapsulate session state variables, why not use an extension method?

```
public static class SessionExtensionMethods
{
    private const string SessionUserNameKey = "UName";

    // set the session value (pass null to remove)
    public static void UserName(this HttpSessionStateBase session, string value)
    {
        if (value == null) session.Remove(SessionUserNameKey);
        else session[SessionUserNameKey] = value;
    }

    // get the session value
    public static string UserName(this HttpSessionStateBase session)
    {
        var value = session[SessionUserNameKey];
        return value != null ? value.ToString() : null;
    }
}
```

Then, in your controller, you can do this to get & set the session value:

```
// set the value
Session.UserName("SomeUserName");

// get the value
var sessionUserName = Session.UserName();

// clear the value 
Sesssion.UserName(null);
```

There is no need for a base controller class here. All you need to do is make sure your controller references the namespace that the `SessionExtensionMethods` class is declared in.